# When does angular 2 call onDestroy on a component?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am not able to figure out when does the angular decide to call *onDestory* event?

When I toggle the component with `*ngIF` directive, onDestory is not called and the state of the component is maintained as if it is using the same instance of the component?

Can anybody elaborate as to when angular(2) destroys component? And how to achieve newer instance of component when toggling with `*ngIf`?

Comment: when ever you change routes or even close the session the component onDestroy is called , if you want a new instance of component on toggling you might need to look at event emitters and have components nested that well toggle new components

Comment: @RahulSingh, do you have a document reference somewhere? It's hard to find any reference about this.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 13):

Most DOM manipulations in Angular are performed using [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef). In particular, this mechanism [is used internally](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b1f8eb14c8cd1f415b07d72e09d14bed77c8d4ac/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L133) by `ngIf`:

```
private _updateView() {
    ...
    this._viewContainer.clear();
    ...
      this._thenViewRef =
          this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._thenTemplateRef, this._context);
    }
  }
```

and [router-outlet](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b1f8eb14c8cd1f415b07d72e09d14bed77c8d4ac/packages/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L99):

```
@Directive({selector: 'router-outlet', exportAs: 'outlet'})
export class RouterOutlet implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
    constructor(..., private location: ViewContainerRef, ...)
    detach(): ComponentRef<any> {
        ...
        this.location.detach();
        ...
    }
    attach(ref: ComponentRef<any>, activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
        ...
        this.location.insert(ref.hostView);
    }
```

Whenever either `viewContainer.clear()` or `viewContainer.remove(index)` method is called the relevant components or embedded  views (created with `ng-template`) are removed and `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook is called on them.

> Can anybody elaborate as to when angular(2) destroys component?

This will happen when using structural directives like `ngIf` and `ngFor`, when router navigates away from current `router-outlet` directive or when you manually remove dynamic components or embedded views using `viewContainerRef`.

You can read more about DOM manipulation using `ViewContainerRef` in:

- [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02)

Comment: I'm a little surprised that your answer was given so few upvotes, this is such an important thing about angular